# Computational complexity of graph operations

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, computational-mathematics

I am trying to understand computational complexity in the context of algorithms applied to graphs. In particular, I am wondering about the complexity of the following algorithm.

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a connected simple finite undirected graph.

1.) Label the vertices of $G$ with labels from $1$ to $|V|$ where each label appears exactly once.

2.) Calculate the $k$-fold cartesian product $G_k =(V^k, E_k)$ of $G$ with itself for a positive integer $k<|V|$.

3.) Remove all vertices $\bar{v}\in V^k$ which contain the label $1$ as well as the corresponding edges.

For a graph with $n$ vertices, the first step takes exactly $n$ operations. The third step takes $O( n^k)$ operations since we have to look at every vertex of $V^k$ exactly once and delete it or keep it.
But I am not sure about the second step. Intuitively the whole algorithm should run in polynomial time but I am not sure and I am completely unexperienced in this area.

Thanks for any help :-)

Comment: Is $k$ an input or a constant?

Comment: $k$ is an input in the sens that you may choose a $k$ for which the algorithm runs.